# Is there any function to substract date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, difference

I need to subtract months from employee hire date

Employee Hire Date = 12/08/2018

previous experience = 0.92 (i.e. 11 months)

I want calculation like

hire date - previous experience = new hire date

is there any function for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're after the [`add_months`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html#GUID-B8C74443-DF32-4B7C-857F-28D557381543) function.

This accepts two parameters: the date and the number of months you're trying to add.

If you pass a negative number in as the second parameter, you'll subtract months.

For example:

```
select to_date('23/07/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt,
       add_months(to_date('23/07/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), -1) prev_month_dt
FROM   dual;

DT          PREV_MONTH_DT
----------- -------------
23/07/2019  23/06/2019
```

Comment: tried below query but wrong output

select to_char(add_months('10/12/2018', - 9.2 * 12),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual

output 
20/10/0001

Comment: you should be using `to_date` to convert strings into dates; instead your string is undergoing implicit conversion using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter as the format mask, which is probably why you're getting the wrong year. You want `select to_char(add_months(to_date('10/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), - 9.2 * 12), 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;` If the value you're passing into the add_months is already of DATE datatype (e.g. you're passing a variable or a column name), you don't need to convert it to a date, since it's already in the right datatype.

Comment: If you are satisfied with just the date, in Oracle a date constant can be specified as `date '2018-12-10'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try just subtracting that many days from the hire date:

```
SELECT
    date_hire,
    date_hire - 365*exp AS hire_date_new
FROM yourTable;
```

This assumes that a year is 365 days, which is not strictly true since leap years have 366 days.  Hopefully you won't mind hiring someone slightly earlier or later.

Comment: tried below query but wrong output 

select to_char(add_months('10/12/2018', - 9.2 * 12),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual 

output : 20/10/0001

Comment: @Abhijitjadhav You are running someone else's answer `:-)` ... I suggested subtracting days from the hire date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_months()` to add a fraction of a year:

```
select add_months(hiredate, - prev_exp * 12)
```

Or convert to days:

```
select hiredate - 365 * prev_exp
```

Comment: tried below query but wrong output

select add_months('10/12/2018', - 0.92 * 12) from dual

output : 0010-01-20 18:00

Comment: @Abhijitjadhav . . . Express the date as `date '2018-10-12'`.